# Find rows where "date" was made within a week

Tags: mysql, timestamp

So basically I am trying to make a function to show popular articles on my website.

I am wandering how in mysql to find rows where they where made a week or under ago? When the date fields data is from a unix timestamp like "1283124091"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 where lastActivity > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 day)
```

Note that this is 7 days worth of seconds.

If you want activity of last 7 calendar days

```
 where lastActivity > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 day)
```